# Completeness of a set of functions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

We know Fourier basis $e^{i k \xi \cdot x}$ forms a $L^2$ complete basis, $|\xi| = 1$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$. I would like to know if $k$ belongs to a open interval, do we still have the completeness.

e.g.,

If $\phi(x)\in C_c^{\infty}$, and

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi(x) e^{i k \xi \cdot x} dx = 0,$$

for all $k\in [0, r]$ for some $r>0$ and for all $|\xi| = 1$, can we conclude that

$$\phi(x) = 0.$$

---

update: From TrialAndError's comment, taking derivative with respect to $k$ at $k = 0$ will be enough to produce this result.

Comment: Is that for some $r>0$ and **all** $\|\xi\|=1$?

Comment: If you have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{i\xi\cdot x}dx=0$ for all $|\xi|\le r$ for some $r > 0$, then $\phi=0$ because all partial derivatives with respect to $\xi$ evaluated at $\xi=0$ must be $0$, which gives $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\phi(x)p(x)dx=0$ for all polynomials in $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_d$.

Comment: @TrialAndError so I can say whatever $r$ is, if it is positive, then this is true. right?

Comment: @copper.hat yes.

Comment: What you can say is that the closure of the linear span must be dense.

Comment: @TrialAndError I got it. thanks. : )